# How to resolve "expecting class body" error in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, runnable, android-handler

The code:

```
var shouldStopLoop = false

val handler = object : Handler()
val runnable = object: Runnable   // The error occurs here
{
    override fun run() {
        getSubsData()
        if(!shouldStopLoop)
        {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000)
        }
    }
}

handler.post(runnable)
```

The *Expecting a class body* error occurs while I am trying to create the `val runnable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

```
// This function takes a lambda extension function
// on class Runnable as the parameter. It is
// known as lambda with a receiver.
inline fun runnable(crossinline body: Runnable.() -> Unit) = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() = body()
}

fun usingRunnable() {
    val handler = Handler()
    val runnableCode = runnable {
        getSubsData()
        if(!shouldStopLoop)
        {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000)
        }
    }
    handler.post(runnableCode)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The error occurs because you are treating `Handler` as an abstract class in the following statement:

`val handler = object : Handler()`

This statement needs a class body after it as the error says, like this:

`val handler = object : Handler(){}`

However, as `Handler` is not an abstract class, a more appropriate statement will be:

`val handler = Handler()`